# how can i remove div tag with all child with python and beautifullsoup

Tags: python, html, text

note : i have many div in my text, but i want only delete this Especially  div with all of child

```
<div ng-if="comment.repliesCount&amp;&amp;showReplies" class="ng-scope"> 

    <div
        <div



        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tryout clear or remove method
for element in child.children: element.clear()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html='''
<div>
    <div>test value</div>
    <div ng-if="comment.repliesCount&amp;&amp;showReplies" class="ng-scope"> 
        <div>
            <div>
                noise
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
# if comment.repliesCount&amp;&amp;showReplies is unique, or first appears
html = doc.removeElement('div',attr='ng-if',value='comment.repliesCount&amp;&amp;showReplies')
# if ng-scope is unique, or first appears
html = doc.removeElement('div',attr='class',value='ng-scope')
# If none of the above works, try the following one. 'test value' is a string that can locate the div to be deleted
html = doc.removeElement('div',attr='class',value='ng-scope',start='test value')
print (html)
```

result: `<div><div>test value</div></div>`

Answer (score -1):

here an example :

```
import re

html='<div ng-if="comment.repliesCount&amp;&amp;showReplies" class="ng-scope"><div><div>HI !</div></div></div>'

def removehtml(html):
  cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
  cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', html)
  return cleantext

print(removehtml(html))
```

Comment: @GillesQuenot then ?

Comment: Check my answer using xpath